# Is there any alternative way for css adjacent selector "+"?

Tags: css

I have done what I want to do but I wonder about for an alternative way?

```css
#div1:hover + #div2
```

When the pointer on div1 only div2 will chance. That's all.

Comment: Why? What's wrong with that way? You want it shorter? Timings/effect is wrong? Wrong elements being affected?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP There is no problem, only wondering. Maybe there is a better way that I don't know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your given selector already works then there isn't really an alternative (unless you count something like `#div1:hover ~ #div2`, which is virtually identical anyway).

You can only affect a different element when some other element is `:hover` if the structure supports such a selector. In your case, `#div1` and `#div2` are adjacent siblings, so they can be represented by either `#div1 + #div2` or `#div1 ~ #div2`:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

And it's just a matter of adding `:hover` to `#div1`.

Since you already have `+` and it works, just stick with `+`. Any questions about performance and such need not be asked.

Comment: "You can only affect a different element when some other element is :hover if the structure supports such a selector." When is it impossible?